# What does "canon" mean?

Tags: discussion, canon

Does it mean "as it relates to the original source"? The word drives me crazy. I have looked it up on google and it takes me to either the camera brand or cannons.

Comment: @phantom42 I think the two should be merged or something.

Answer (score 9):

The term **[Canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_%28fiction%29)** in works of fiction refers to any 'authoritative' body of work related to said work of fiction.

> In fiction, canon is the material accepted as part of the story in an individual universe of that story.
> <sup>*-[Canon (fiction), Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_%28fiction%29)*</sup>

'Authoritative' can refer to any work which is approved or written specifically *by* the original author(s). This can include extra material such as:

- Games

  - Video games
  - Board games
  - etc
- Director's Cuts and
- Behind the scenes
- Interviews
- Correspondence

Any other works are considered to be works of [**Fan Fiction**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_fiction) and not necessarily authorised by the original author(s).

---

For example, in the world created by **[George. R. R. Martin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_R._R._Martin)** for his books series *[A Song of Ice and Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire)* the following works are considered ***canon***:

- *[A Song of Ice and Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire)*
- *[The Tales of Dunk and Egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Dunk_and_Egg)*
- *[The World of Ice and Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_of_Ice_%26_Fire)*
- [Westeros.org](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/)
- [So Spake Martin](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/) - to a certain degree

There are some *special* cases; for example, *A Song of Ice and Fire* has a television adaptation ([*Game of Thrones - HBO*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones)) which *is* approved by the author (George R. R. Martin), but [tends to deviate from the original storyline in the book(s)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2902/21267).